# WPF - setting HorizontalAlignment= Stretch to Textbox in StackPanel

Tags: wpf, stackpanel, autosize

Why doesn't a textbox stretch to fill space in a stackpanel? Is this by design? In a grid, the textbox stretches as expected.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it's by design. The `StackPanel` will allocate the space the `TextBox` asks for. If you haven't set a width on the `TextBox`, it will require only enough width to fit its text.

Answer (score 9):

Kent's answer seems right.
To still force override the StackPanel behavior, I think you'd need to dynamically compute-set the Width property of the contained elements OR some funky override of [MeasureOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride.aspx). I'd rather use another layout manager/panel. Some things I noted..

- The default value for HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment properties of child elements is **Stretch** (if you don't specify one explicitly).
- The StackPanel will stretch elements based on its Orientation property value. So

  - Orientation=Horizontal means all elements will be vertically stretched to max. Elements flow horizontally.
  - Orientation=Vertical means all elements will be horiz stretched to max. Elements flow vertically.
- Unless explicitly specified, Width and Height of child elements are NaN. If you specify an explicit value, StackPanel will honor them over the Horiz and Vert Alignment settings.
- The StackPanel itself has HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment that adds a further layout twist. You can experiment with this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752328.aspx).

[StackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx)

> The default value is stretch for both
>   HorizontalAlignment and
>   VerticalAlignment of content that is
>   contained in a StackPanel.

[HorizontalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment.aspx)

> When Height and Width properties are
>   explicitly set on an element, these
>   measurements take higher precedent
>   during layout and will cancel the
>   typical effects of setting
>   HorizontalAlignment to Stretch.

Answer (score 4):

I needed items to be sized evenly, but stacked vertically.

I used a UniformGrid, and set the Columns property to 1.  (tested with a TextBox, and it stretches like you want)

Comment: This was the exact answer I needed for a similar layout issue with Buttons. Thanks!