# Setting TextBox.Width="*" via Code

Tags: wpf, textbox, autosize

Does anyone know how to set the TextBox.Width property to fill up the remainder of the parent container in code?  In Xaml, I would simply set the Width property to *, but I can't figure out how to do this in code.

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

Related answers:

[WPF - setting HorizontalAlignment= Stretch to Textbox in StackPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405935/wpf-setting-horizontalalignment-stretch-to-texbox-in-stackpanel)

[HorizontalAlignment=Stretch, MaxWidth, and Left aligned at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280331/wpf-horizontalalignmentstretch-maxwidth-and-left-aligned-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 4):

Try the following

```
textBox.Width = Double.NaN;
```

Double.NaN (not a number) is the equivalent of any size.